# Azure Data Factory CSV with double quotes

Tags: azure, double-quotes, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that retrieves an FTP hosted CSV file. It is comma delimited with double quote identifiers. The issue exists where a string is encapsulated in double quotes, but the string itself contains double quotes.

string example: `"Spring Sale" this year.`

How it looks in the csv (followed and lead by two null columns):

```
"","""Spring Sale"" this year",""
```

SSIS handles this fine, but Data Factory wants to transform it into an extra column that isn't separated by a comma. I have removed the extra quotes on this line and it works fine.

Is there a way around this besides altering the source?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got this to work using `Escape character` set as quote (`"`) with the Azure Data Factory Copy Task.  Screen shot:

[image: ADF Copy Task]

This was based on a file as per your spec:

`"","""Spring Sale"" this year",""`

and also worked as in insert into an Azure SQL Database table.  The sample JSON:

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "linkedService2",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": "quotes.txt",
                "container": "someContainer"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\"",
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "Prop_0",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Prop_1",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Prop_2",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Maybe the example file is too simple but it did work for me in this configuration.

Alternately, just use SSIS and host it in Data Factory.

Comment: I have since torn down the environment and can't validate but i dont recall that i tried this. We abandoned ADF due to lack of features and haven't researched SSIS runtime yet. I will remember this if we revisit it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This does work, and properly supports the CSV RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Azure Data Factory should have this enabled by default to " and not \

Comment: Does not work for me either :(    I have no control about incoming values, they just can and do contain quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this solution. It helped me a lot. You have many beers from me :)))