# Azure Data Factory: Copying files from azure data lake storage to an azure SQL database stg table using copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

[image: CSV File example]

I have a csv file which is stored in azure data lake and I want to move it to azure SQL database table. Now my problem is the table has 2 extra columns: pipelineid and source_filename and my csv file do not (expected). So during the copy activity, I need to populate 2 columns along with the data of the csv files form data lake and then move it to the respective table. I tried using the "Additional columns" part in the source section of the copy activity but after running the pipeline it throws the below error :

"ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'credits_20231114153123.csv' with row number 2: found more columns than expected column count 3.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'".

In short, the columns are not getting copied by the copy activity to the final SQL table. How can i do this? Can anyone please help? I am new to ADF.

This is an example data in the cast column (2nd row of data):

[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': None}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]

similarly is the data in the Crew column.

[image: Source dataset settings - Datalake gen2]

[image: Tgt dataset settings - Azure SQL]

Comment: What is the delimiter you use? Check in the 2nd row, if you are having delimiter in the data itself. This may lead to additional column in that row

Comment: I have updated with an image and an example data

Comment: Could you share the dataset settings also?

Comment: yes of course!!

Comment: Open your csv file in notepad and check if they are wrapped within double quotes?

Comment: yes it is wrapped within double quotes. The first column Cast, wrapped in double quotes followed by a comma and then the second column Crew wrapped in double quotes followed by a comma and finally the id column data which is numeric and no double quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256182/discussion-between-chipz-and-aswin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was the problem with the escape character. I got the solution from this post: [Azure Data Factory CSV with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501708/azure-data-factory-csv-with-double-quotes)

When I changed my escape character to double quotes it worked.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. **Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link?** Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.